# JavaScript - Map over two object arrays, match key, and store key and property as array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have two arrays:

Array 1:

```
['0000037_165', '0000037_62', '0000037_74', '0000037_165', ...]
```

Array 2:

```
[
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 1'},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 2'},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_62', Description: 'Description 1'},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_74', Description: 'Description 1'},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 1'},
 ...
]
```

I need to map over both arrays and check if the 'SiteUniqueID' from array 2 exists in array 1. If it exists in array 1 I then need to push the ID and the description into a new array.

As seen in Array 2, a Site ID may have more than one description.

So, the tricky part is that if the ID exists twice in array 2, then the description should be an array of all of the descriptions.

I have played around with a mixture of .map() and .find() with no luck so far.

I would like the resulting array to look like this:

```
[
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: ['Description 1', 'Description2']},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_62', Description: ['Description 1']},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_74', Description: ['Description 1']},
 {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: ['Description 1']},
  ...
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the first array relevant here? It looks like it is grouping consecutive items with the same `SiteUniqueID` in Array2.

Comment: Yes, Array 2 is an open SQL query of all SiteIDs whereas Array 1 is in the request body, so we only want to return the IDs that exist in Array 1

Comment: What is the logic for grouping the `0000037_165` separately? Do we need to group consecutive items or is there any other logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should also work:

```js
var array1 = new Set(['0000037_165', '0000037_62', '0000037_74', '0000037_165'])

var array2 = [
    {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 1'},
    {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 2'},
    {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_62', Description: 'Description 1'},
    {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_74', Description: 'Description 1'},
    {SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165', Description: 'Description 1'}]

var newArray = [];

array1.forEach(x => {
    var results = array2.filter(y => y.SiteUniqueID === x);
    if (results?.length)
        newArray.push({SiteUniqueID: x, Description: results.map(z => z.Description)})
})

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code out.

```js
let arr1 = ['0000037_165', '0000037_62', '0000037_74', '0000037_165'];
let arr2 = [{
        SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165',
        Description: 'Description 1'
    },
    {
        SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165',
        Description: 'Description 2'
    },
    {
        SiteUniqueID: '0000037_62',
        Description: 'Description 1'
    },
    {
        SiteUniqueID: '0000037_74',
        Description: 'Description 1'
    },
    {
        SiteUniqueID: '0000037_165',
        Description: 'Description 1'
    },

]

let arrMod = [];

arr2.forEach(a => {
    if (arr1.includes(a.SiteUniqueID)) {

        let index = arrMod.findIndex(arrMod => arrMod.SiteUniqueID === a.SiteUniqueID);
        if (index !== -1) {
            arrMod[index].Description.push(a.Description);
        } else {
            arrMod.push({
                SiteUniqueID: a.SiteUniqueID,
                Description: [a.Description]
            });
        }

    }

});

console.log(arrMod);
```

Comment: Worked great, accepted other answer for conciseness